React module @mui-icons-material installation issues
I had a working React application built on NodeJS v20.17.0. I have been using @mui/material for some components successfully and wanted to add some icons to a Drawer component using @mui-icons-material. When I ran $npm install @mui/material, it took a while but seemed to install it correctly in my package.json file, but not in my application repo's node_modules folder. I noticed that there is another folder from the original NodeJS install called node_modules outside of my repo directory. After installing @mui/material without error, I tried to run $npm install and $npm -v and get the following error:
 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1228
   throw err;
   ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Scripts\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }

 Node.js v20.17.0
 Could not determine Node.js install directory
 

What is happening here and how can I get @mui/icons-material to install correctly? In searching it seems that this may be related to my Node version but I am not sure.


Try to delete the node_modules folder and running npm install --legacy-peer-deps again. If the issue still persists  try to downgrade the material icon library to a previous stable version.


Hmm, I deleted the node_modules folder but I am getting the same error. I cannot find npm.

Were you using source control? Can you return to a point where the application was working, and retry from there? Seems you are using windows - can you check the npm & node installations to see if they match with your error? See also this github issue
